# Using VBA How to copy the rich text from one outlook item to another

Tags: vba, outlook, richtext

I'm using an Outlook 2019 to copy a message from one outlook item to another.  The problem is that it doesn't copy Rich Text.  Here's a sample of the code I'm using.  It's reduced significantly for this posting:

```
Option Explicit
Sub EmailTest()

Dim objOutlookApp               As Object
Dim objOriginalItem             As Object
Dim objNewItem                  As Object
Dim objInspector                As Object
Dim objAccount                  As Object
Dim strEmailAddress             As String

'Set objInspector
Set objInspector = Application.ActiveInspector

'Set objOriginalItem so that it can be referenced
Set objOriginalItem = objInspector.CurrentItem

'Set objNewItem to create the new message.
Set objNewItem = Application.CreateItem(0)

'Set objOutlook App
Set objOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

'Copy the original Body into the new item Body
objNewItem.Body = objOriginalItem.Body

'Copy the original Subject into the new item Subject
objNewItem.Subject = objOriginalItem.Subject

    'Assign strEmailAddress
    strEmailAddress = "myname@gmail.com"

    'Set the fields of the MailItem.  Note:  objNewItem.Body was previously set
    With objNewItem
        .Display
        .Subject = objOriginalItem.Subject
        .To = strEmailAddress
        .Send
    End With
    Set objNewItem = Nothing

Set objOriginalItem = Nothing
Set objInspector = Nothing
Set objOutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Here's the original message body:
***This is some bold Italicized text***,
This is some normal text
This is a link https://msn.com
This is some normal text
***Sincerely,

Me***

Unfortunately, this is what is sent:
This is some bold Italicized text,
This is some normal text
This is a link https://msn.com https://msn.com/
This is some normal text
Sincerely,
Me

Question:  How do I use VBA to send the message preserving the Rich Text attributes as well as the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to create a new `Application` instance in the code:

```
'Set objOutlook App
Set objOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Note, you are using a plain text `Body` property to copy the message content:

```
'Copy the original Body into the new item Body
objNewItem.Body = objOriginalItem.Body
```

Instead, you need to use HTMLBody property:

```
'Copy the original Body into the new item Body
objNewItem.HTMLBody = objOriginalItem.HTMLBody
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides avoiding to copy the plain text `Body` property (instead of using `HTMLBody` or `RtfBVody` deepening on the item'ss format), you can copy all properties using `MailItem.Copy` and then `MailItem.Move`.